# Why am i getting segmentation fault in this function?

Tags: c++, memory-management, segmentation-fault, g++, queue

I have tried all possible ways. I think there is some logical error in the function `findlink()` 
The purpose of this function is to find and return a pattern from the argument `abc`.
**For example, if `abc` is "Hello,My name is **Lorem ipsum sit amet ** and I am a student.", then findlink will return "Lorem ipsum sit amet".** i.e. it returns the text between double asterisk. But due to some reason I am getting segmentation fault, though I have debugged and figured out that the fault is concerned with this function only, but I am unable to discover why.

```
char *findlink(char *abc)
{
    if(abc==NULL)
        return NULL;
    cout<<"Findlink called for : "<<abc<<endl;
    int i=0,flag=0,flag1=0,len=0;
    char *link;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(abc)-1;i++)
    {
        if(abc[i]=='*' && abc[i+1]=='*' && flag==0)
        {
            flag=1;
            i+=2;
        }
        if(abc[i]=='*' && abc[i+1]=='*' && flag==1)
        {
            flag=0;
            flag1=1;
            i+=2;
        }
        if(flag==1 && flag1!=1)
            link[len++]=abc[i];
        if(flag1==1)
        {
            link[len++]='\0';
            cout<<"Returning "<<link<<endl;
            return link;
        }
    }
    cout<<"Returning NULL\n";
    return NULL;
}
```

.
Following is the full code for reference.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
ifstream infile;
ofstream outfile;
struct queue
{
    struct node *front;
    struct node *rear;
};
struct queue* createqueue()
{
    struct queue *temp=new queue;
    temp->front=NULL;
    temp->rear=NULL;
    return temp;
}
struct node
{
    struct node *next;
    char *value;
};
struct node * createnode(char *val)
{
    struct node *new1=new node;
    new1->next=NULL;
    new1->value=val;
    return new1;
}
struct queue *push(char *val,struct queue *queue1)
{
    struct node *new1=createnode(val);
    if(queue1->front==NULL && queue1->rear==NULL)
    {
        queue1->front=queue1->rear=new node;
        queue1->rear=new1;
        queue1->front=new1;
    }
    else
    {
        queue1->rear->next=new node;
        queue1->rear->next=new1;
        queue1->rear=queue1->rear->next;
    }
    return queue1;
}
struct queue *push(string val,struct queue *queue1) //overloaded function push for string arguments
{
    char* cstr = new char[val.length() +1]; 
    strcpy(cstr, val.c_str()); 
    queue1=push(cstr,queue1);
    return queue1;
};
struct queue *pop(struct queue *queue1)
{
    struct node *temp=new node;
    if(queue1->front==NULL)
        return NULL;
    else if(queue1->front==queue1->rear)
    {
        temp=queue1->front;
        queue1->front=NULL;
        queue1->rear=NULL;
        cout<<"POP: Poping: "<<temp->value<<endl;
        return queue1;
    }
    else
    {
        temp=queue1->front;
        queue1->front=queue1->front->next;
        cout<<"POP: Poping: "<<temp->value<<endl;
        return queue1;
    }
}
struct queue *scanitall(struct queue *queue1)       //reads the contents from outputproject.txt and pushes all the contents in a queue
{
    string line;
    infile.open("outputproject.txt");
    while(getline(infile,line))
    {                    
        char *line1=new char[line.length()+1];
        strcpy(line1,line.c_str());
        queue1=push(line1,queue1);
    }
    infile.close();
    return queue1;
}
int search(struct queue* queue1,char *val)  //returns 1 if val found in queue1 else 0
{
    //cout<<"SEARCH called\n";
    if(queue1->front==NULL || queue1->rear==NULL)
        return 0;
    struct node *temp=new node;
    temp=queue1->front;
    while(temp)
    {
        if(strcmp(temp->value,val)==0)
            return 1;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
char *findlink(char *abc)
{
    if(abc==NULL)
        return NULL;
    cout<<"Findlink called for : "<<abc<<endl;
    int i=0,flag=0,flag1=0,len=0;
    char *link;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(abc)-1;i++)
    {
        if(abc[i]=='*' && abc[i+1]=='*' && flag==0)
        {
            flag=1;
            i+=2;
        }
        if(abc[i]=='*' && abc[i+1]=='*' && flag==1)
        {
            flag=0;
            flag1=1;
            i+=2;
        }
        if(flag==1 && flag1!=1)
            link[len++]=abc[i];
        if(flag1==1)
        {
            link[len++]='\0';
            cout<<"Returning "<<link<<endl;
            return link;
        }
    }
    cout<<"Returning NULL\n";
    return NULL;
}
struct queue *processit(struct queue *queue1,char *abc) //identifies link text in inputproject.txt
{
    //cout<<"PROCESSIT called\n";
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("outputproject.txt",ios::app);
    if(!outfile)
        cout<<"PROCESSIT: Error file not opened!\n";
    char *link;
    link=findlink(abc);
    if(link)
        cout<<"Caught: "<<link<<endl;
    if(link)
        if(search(queue1,link)==0)
            {
                cout<<"^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n";
                outfile<<link<<endl;
                queue1=push(link,queue1);
            }
    outfile.close();
    return queue1;
}
void openallfiles(struct queue *queue1)
{
    if(!queue1->rear)
        cout<<"Queue Empty\n";
    else
    {
        struct node *temp=new node;
        temp=queue1->front;
        string line;
        while(temp)
        {
            ifstream infile;
            infile.open(temp->value);
            if(!infile)
            {
                cout<<"openallfiles:File not opened\n";
                return;
            }
            while(getline(infile,line))
            {
                cout<<line<<endl;
            }
            infile.close();
            if(temp)
                temp=temp->next;
        }
    }
}/*
struct queue *findlinks(struct queue *crawl1,ifstream infile)
{

}
crawl(struct queue *crawl1)
{
    ifstream infile1,infile2;
    infile1.open("inputproject.txt");
    crawl1=findlinks(crawl1,infile1);
}*/
void display(struct queue *queue1)
{
    if(queue1->front)
    {
        struct node *temp=queue1->front;
        while(temp)
        {
            cout<<"data:"<<temp->value<<endl;
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Sorry queue empty\n";
    }
}
int main()
{
    struct queue *queue1=createqueue();
    struct queue *crawl1=createqueue();
    queue1=scanitall(queue1);       //push all contents of outputproject.txt in  a queue
    display(queue1);
    //cout<<"Poping:\n";
    /*while(queue1->rear)
        queue1=pop(queue1);*/
    string line;
    char *line1;
    infile.open("inputproject.txt");
    while(getline(infile,line))
    {
        line1=new char[line.length()+1];
        strcpy(line1,line.c_str());
        queue1=processit(queue1,line1);
    }
    infile.close();
    openallfiles(queue1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `strncpy` until you're **read** and **understood** its documentation. It is **not** a "safe" dropin replacement for `strcpy`. If your source string is too long, `strncpy` will **postpone** the buffer overrun; it won't prevent it.

Answer (score 2):

The `string` class has a constructor that takes a NULL-terminated C-string. No use of `strncpy()` in your case. To convert from a `C-String` to a `string` you do it directly. Example:

```
char MyCharArray[] = "Whatever";

std::string MyStandardString(MyCharArray); // done
```

On the other hand, to convert a `string` to a `C-String` you can use the built in function of the class `string` which is *the apply of the D3 rule*:

`char YourCharArray = YourString.c_str();`

But that is considered bad practice, why? Because when your string "dies", so your char array.

You, instead, need to use something like this:

```
std::string YourString = "hello world";
char* YourCharArray = new char[YourString.length() + 1]; // notice the "new", means your pointer "allocated" new memory just for itself

std::strcpy(YourCharArray, YourString.c_str());
delete[] YourCharArray; // this and only this will kill your CharArray. Which you "HAVE" to in order to "free" the memory once your program ends executing
```

Look here for [**Documentation**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/copy/) on `C-String` to `string` and [**Here**](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/100714/) for `string` to `C-String`

Advice: Don't practice the use of `using namespace std;` Why? Look here: [Why is “using namespace std” in C++ considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: sir,why should i avoid using namespace std?

Comment: @rahul I edited my answer and added a reference for you.

Comment: I think the problem is deeper than this.  The problem code calls `push` which ends up storing a pointer to the local array.  Technically, the next time round the while-loop this pointer is invalid (although in practise it will always be the same).  The means that every node ends up holding the same (random) string.

Comment: @FirstStep, Sir thank you so so much, I had been debugging this code for 2 weeks but not got any satisfactory answer until now,thank you very much

Comment: @FirstStep , sir I have edited the question for seg fault.Can you help me?

Comment: @rahul you removed the whole question and added a new one. This in not a proper way to ask for solutions on this website. Instead, you need to keep the old one and **Ask** a brand new question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `struct node` holds a pointer to char.  If you trace down all the calls nothing allocates a copy of `line1`, so all the nodes end up pointing at the same buffer.  (Technically, it is undefined behaviour because `line1` ceases to exist each time round the `while` loop, in practise though, they will all point to the same place on the stack.)

The fix is to make `struct node` hold a `std::string`, and then instead of calling `strncpy`, you can just push the string.